# JSON Parsing Using Jackson Library

Tags: android, json, jackson

My `JSON` data looks like this:

```
[
{
  "id":1,
  "ad_name":"Test Ad",
  "ad_text":"This is my ad text"
},
{
  "id":2,
  "ad_name":"Test Ad",
  "ad_text":"This is my ad text"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "ad_name":"Test Ad",
  "ad_text":"This is my ad text"
},
{
  "id":4,
  "ad_name":"Test Ad",
  "ad_text":"This is my ad text"
},
{
  "id":5,
  "ad_name":"Test Ad",
  "ad_text":"This is my ad text"
}
]
```

I'm using Jackson Library to parse it, here is my code for that:

```
try {
        jParser = jfactory.createParser(array);

        while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {

            String fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();

            if (fieldname != null) {

                if ("id".equals(fieldname)) {
                    jParser.nextToken();
                    if (jParser.getText() != null)
                        id = jParser.getText();

                    System.out.println(id);
                }

                if ("ad_name".equals(fieldname)) {
                    jParser.nextToken();
                    if (jParser.getText() != null)
                        ad_name = jParser.getText();

                    System.out.println(ad_name);
                }

                if ("ad_text".equals(fieldname)) {
                    jParser.nextToken();
                    if (jParser.getText() != null)
                        ad_text = jParser.getText();

                    System.out.println(ad_text);
                }
            }

        }

        jParser.close();
        return adsList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My parsing and all stuff are working fine. But when I'm printing values in logs, I'm getting duplicate values, means every `JSONObject` is printing two times.

What am I missing here? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: actually if you use GSON library, this JSON will be parsed in one line only

Comment: Haven't considered that library. But I think JACKSON library is much faster than other library out there. Do you have any idea about the problem I'm facing.

Comment: ok.but GSON is fastest

Comment: Comparison of Jackson and Gson: http://www.doublecloud.org/2015/03/gson-vs-jackson-which-to-use-for-json-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it using the following parsing method, I have used the same Jackson library for parsing it:

```
try {

        jParser = jfactory.createParser(array);

        if (jParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {

            while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {

                if (jParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {

                    String fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();

                    if (fieldname != null) {

                        if ("id".equals(fieldname)) {
                            jParser.nextToken();
                            if (jParser.getText() != null)
                                id = jParser.getText();
                        }
                    }

                    if (jParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {

                        String fieldname1 = jParser.getCurrentName();

                        if ("ad_name".equals(fieldname1)) {
                            jParser.nextToken();
                            if (jParser.getText() != null)
                                ad_name = jParser.getText();
                        }
                    }

                    if (jParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {

                        String fieldname2 = jParser.getCurrentName();

                        if ("ad_text".equals(fieldname2)) {
                            jParser.nextToken();
                            if (jParser.getText() != null)
                                ad_text = jParser.getText();
                        }
                    }

                    if (jParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {

                        String fieldname3 = jParser.getCurrentName();

                        if ("ad_image_url".equals(fieldname3)) {
                            jParser.nextToken();
                            if (jParser.getText() != null)
                                ad_image_url = jParser.getText();
                        }
                    }

                    if (jParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {

                        String fieldname4 = jParser.getCurrentName();

                        if ("ad_click_url".equals(fieldname4)) {
                            jParser.nextToken();
                            if (jParser.getText() != null)
                                ad_click_url = jParser.getText();

                        }

                        adsList.add(new AllAdsModel(id, ad_name, ad_text,
                                ad_image_url, ad_click_url));
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        jParser.close();
        return adsList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope, it will help others!

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON is really simple. You can easily deserialize it to Java POJO objects with this example. Create simple POJO for array item.

```
class Ad {

    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("ad_name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("ad_text")
    private String text;

        //getters, setters, toString()
}
```

And now, you can deserialize it like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Ad[] array = mapper.readValue(json, Ad[].class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Above program prints:

```
[Ad [id=1, name=Test Ad, text=This is my ad text], Ad [id=2, name=Test Ad, text=This is my ad text], Ad [id=3, name=Test Ad, text=This is my ad text], Ad [id=4, name=Test Ad, text=This is my ad text], Ad [id=5, name=Test Ad, text=This is my ad text]]
```

I would like to help you with your source code, but it is not complete. For me your source code prints each property only once. Maybe you have a bug in the code which we are not able to see?

Comment: Jackson Gradle dependency: `compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0'`

Answer (score 3):

I do not know actually what is wrong with your code, but if you parse JSON the way you do, you actually don't need Jackson. You might as well use JSONObject.

You can do it more efficiently this way with Jackson:

**Ad.java**

```
public class Ad {
 public int id;
 public String ad_name;
 public String ad_text;
}
```

**Parser**

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jsonParser = f.createJsonParser(your_json_string);
jsonParser.nextToken();
List<Ad> adList = new ArrayList<Ad>();
while (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT)) {
   Ad ad = mapper.readValue(jsonParser, Ad.class);
   adList.add(ad);
}
```

- smart thing to have are getters and setters in Ad.java as well.

Comment: Instead of changing it to `ObjectMapper` can't we do things the way I was doing. And I'm using `Object` class for that. Can you suggest the change I have to make to solve my problem.